# How can I print background color on last page with CSS?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to display a solid background color when I print.
I have used

```css
@media print { 
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background: #CCC; 
}
```

And activated "print background graphics" in Chrome and Safari.
But on the last page theres a white spot below because the website does not cover the 100% height of the A4/Letter page.

Photos:

First page: Looks as intended.
[image]

Last page: Theres a empty white space below that I want to fill with color.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `100vh` (Viewport-height), to set your page is full.

For example, on the last page. You have an empty white space below that I want to fill with color. You can try to use the `vh`.

```css
@media print { 
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #CCC; 
}
```

Comment: [_Viewport_ height, actually](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts#css).

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media print{
  body,html{
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background:#ccc;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Apply it like below

```css
     @media print { 
       body, html{
         height: 100%;
         min-height:100%;
         background: #CCC; 
       }
     }
```

Comment: Hi i follow the code correction but Chrome and Safari still does not show the background to full screen.